# How to set the position to UILabel if is inside my detailView (splitView) but I have trouble in the viewDidLoad and willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, screen-rotation

I´m trying to improve an iOS (Objective-C) app. For iPhone/iPod, everything works great, but the problem is for iPad.

In iPad, I used a SplitView to call `indexTable.h` as master and `PlayGround.h` as Detail. Inside PlayGround, I called some classes (for example insideView), but when I start the app in landscape orientation (in iPad), I have UILabels in viewDidLoad (just for iPad, for other devices it's different) with this position:

```
self.labelAirName.frame = CGRectMake((self.insideView.bounds.size.width/2), 110, self.insideView.bounds.size.width/2, 30);
self.labelMaterialName.frame = CGRectMake((self.insideView.bounds.size.width/2), 80, self.insideView.bounds.size.width/2, 30);
self.airLabel.frame = CGRectMake((self.insideView.bounds.size.width/2)-95, 110, 90, 30);
self.materialLabel.frame = CGRectMake((self.insideView.bounds.size.width/2)-95, 80, 90, 30);
```

I use insideView because I need this size as reference and I have

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
//for iPad landscape i call the last mentioned values, because for portrait all the labels change their positions
}
```

when I call `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, it works well, but when I start, the sizes are different.

Is this a problem with my splitView? How can I obtain the DetailView size?

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommends to use `Size class` to achieve different positioning in `Regular` and `Compact` mode. OS kills the application If the manual computation takes large memory as the computation gets executed 60 times a second.

Use autolayout for better performance / Full screen mode is the best option.

if still you wish to do your own computation you may do it in

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

method